# Prevent a property from being called twice

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window with a few text fields and an OK and Cancel button. When I click OK it needs to validate my fields and do stuff with them if they're valid and display an error message if they're not.

In my ViewModel I've got

```
public ICommand OKCommand { get; private set; }
public Action ErrorAction { get; set; }

OKCommand = new BaseCommand(_ =>
{               
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
    {
        // Do stuff with the contents of the fields
        ...
    }
    else ErrorAction();
});

public string ErrorMessage
{
    get
    {
        // Gets the error message for the fields
        ...
    }
}
```

And in my code behind I've got

```
if (ViewModel.ErrorAction == null) ViewModel.ErrorAction = new Action(() => MessageDialog.ShowError(ViewModel.ErrorMessage));
```

My issue is `ErrorMessage` is called twice when there's an error, first in the `OKCommand` and again by `ErrorAction`.

The only solutions I can think of are

1. Accept the second call - it's not the end of the world.
2. Determine whether there is an error in `OKCommand` and set `ErrorMessage` if appropriate

Something like this

```
private bool HasError
{
    get
    {
        // Do the same as ErrorMessage but populate ErrorMessage and return a bool
        ...
    }
}

OKCommand = new BaseCommand(_ =>
{               
    if (!HasError)
    {
        // Do stuff with the contents of the fields
        ...
    }
    else ErrorAction();
});
```

While both work I don't think either is great - the first has a second call and the second adds a level of indirection. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can declare `ErrorAction` as `Action<string>` and pass `ErrorMessage` there explicitly in `OKCommand`.

Comment: Another alternative would be to cache `ErrorMessage` and reset cache when any related property changes (so when property changes - set `_errorMessage` to null, and in `ErrorMessage` getter only calculate new message if `_errorMessage` is null).

Comment: Why is ErrorMessage called twice and why is this a problem? Do you see two messages or what is your issue?

Comment: @mm8 - `OKCommand` checks to see if `ErrorMessage` is empty and calls `ErrorAction` if it isn't. `ErrorAction` then calls `ErrorMessage`. One message id displayed as expected the only (small) issue is there is a second call.

Comment: "OKCommand checks to see if ErrorMessage is empty and calls ErrorAction if it isn't.". So far so good? "ErrorAction then calls ErrorMessage". What exactly does this mean and does this "display another message id"?

Comment: @mm8 Typing mistake on my part - ErrorAction shows a MessageBox with ErrorMessage in. The user then clicks OK to close the MessageBox and then they can further edit the text fields or Cancel and close the window. So, to answer your original question - the user is none the wiser about the second call.

Comment: @Evk - unless I'm missing something I'd have to call `ErrorMessage` and then assign it to a temporary variable and then pass that into `Action<string>`?
- I had thought of doing that, my original implementation used `IDataErrorInfo` and then displayed the error with an adorner. However, the mandate changed to not wanting validation until the end so I changed the implementation to the one above.

Comment: Why are you calling ErrorAction twice?

Comment: @mm8 - I'm not. I've implemented my ErrorAction as described in this blog post - http://jkshay.com/closing-a-wpf-window-using-mvvm-and-minimal-code-behind/ to avoid opening a MessageBox from my ViewModel. So in my OKCommand in my ViewModel I'm calling ErrorMessage and then calling ErrorAction if appropriate. In my View's code behind I'm opening a MessageBox containing ErrorMessage with a delegate.

Comment: I am not following. Code-behind? Why are you displaying another dialog from there...? Obviously you should display only *one* dialog.

Comment: Sorry, the MessageBox is only displayed by the code-behind. The ViewModel is making the first call to ErrorMessage to see if there are errors, if there are it's calling ErrorAction which is then showing a MessageBox with a delegate in the code-behind.

Comment: Yes, call `ErrorMessage` and assign to temp variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided that given none of the options were noticeably better than my current solution I'd stick with that.

For future reference, this [article](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) describes alternative approaches to data validation. However, unfortunately my requirements meant that these were not an easy option for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to validate a TextBox Text:

it's called *[ValidationRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)*

[You can directly see  that there is an error(Error in MouseOverMessage) and the Button is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDhAa.png)

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyValidatorProperties x:Key="properties"/>
        <local:MyCustomValidationRule x:Key="validator" />
        <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                         Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="17">!</TextBlock>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbName" Height="23" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" Margin="10,10,349,286">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="myName" Source="{StaticResource properties}"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:MyCustomValidationRule Type="myName" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <Button x:Name="btnCreate" Content="Create" Width="58" Height="23" Margin="174,10,285,286" >
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=tbRepositoryName}" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

ValidatiorClass:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace TestWpf
{
    class MyCustomValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object p_value, CultureInfo p_cultureInfo)
        {
            switch (Type)
            {
                case "myName":
                    string a_strValue = p_value as string;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_strValue))
                    {
                        Match a_match = Regex.Match((string)p_value, @"^[a-zA-Z\d]+$");
                        return a_match.Success ? new ValidationResult(true, "Name is valid!") : new ValidationResult(false, $"Input should be a Valid Name (a-z, A-Z, 0-9)");
                    }
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Empty name!");
                default:
                    return new ValidationResult(false, $"UnkownValidation Parameter: " + Type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Property bound to TextBox:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestWpf
{
    class MyValidatorProperties : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string m_myName = "";

        public string myName
        {
            get
            {
                return m_myName;
            }
            set
            {
                if (m_myName != value)
                {
                    m_myName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("myName");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

**PS:**
If you don't want to disable the Button and show a message instead you can replace the Button with:

```
<Button x:Name="btnCreate" Content="Create" Width="58" Height="23" Click="btnCreate_Click" />
```

And add the method:

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(System.Windows.Controls.Validation.GetHasError(tbName))
   {
      //Show Message
   }
}
```